# What is an efficient way to many substrings of a string against a case in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I am working on some problems on Hackerrank, where I need to to determine if a string matches a pattern after 1 or 0 elements are removed. If after removing 1 or 0 elements, every character in the string has the same frequency then I want to print "YES". Otherwise I print "NO". The input is a string between 1 and 10^5 characters. What I have works for trivial cases, but times-out on some of the test cases. I should reach some return value, but I think the test cases are just really large input that my code is too inefficient for. Particularly where I use erase, I am copying the string n^2 times where n is the length of the string. Can I work on the string in-place, simply skipping over each element?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


long countFreq(char someChar,string someStr){
    long count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<someStr.size();i++){
        if(someStr[i] == someChar)count += 1;
        }
    return count;}

bool allSameFreq(string someStr){
    long freq = countFreq(someStr[0],someStr);
    for(char someChr:someStr){
        if(countFreq(someChr,someStr)!=freq)return false;
        }
    return true;}


int main(){
    string pattern;
    cin>>pattern;

    if(allSameFreq(pattern)==true){cout<<"YES";return 0;}
    else {
        for(int i=0;i<pattern.size();i++){
            string copy = pattern;
            copy.erase(i,1);
            if(allSameFreq(copy)==true){cout<<"YES";return 0;}
            }
        cout<<"NO";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: It has been pointed out that this can be solved in another way that is less memory intensive. Still, I am curious about the original question: What is an efficient way to iterate over a string (or whatever) and test the "string minus each value" against a condition WITHOUT making a copy of the string each time?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... can't you just calculate the frequency of every character, and if one character is one too high, then the answer is yes?

Comment: Adding to @JamesRoot comment: you need to iterate over string once and store frequences of all characters in array.

Comment: Use `std::map<char, int> cm` for example.  Than all you need to do to store the frequencies is to say `cm[ch]++`, where `ch` is each character from the string you read in.  Start from there -- the rest should be simple.

Comment: @MaxZS: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-valid-string

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: So after putting the counts in a map, if all values are the same OR (if all values are the same except one AND abs(freqCount1 - freqCount2) == 1)... That sounds right.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that efficiently operates on a sublist without making a copy. You have to be able to access pointers to elements of the string, treating the string as a linked list. So depending on how you want to alter the string, you move a pointer or few, saving the values of the pointers you modified.